# find out type of unhandled exception in visual studio 2010 for windows phone

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

My new windows phone 7 application never actually opens in the emulator but rather stays stuck in the Application_UnhandledException-function in App.xaml.cs. This function looks like

```
    // Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
    private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
```

Obviously some unhandled exception has occurred, but I have no clue what it might be. Is there a possibility to find out more about this exception and where its cause might be?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't think this code is the source of the problem. I think the problem is in the initialize function of the MainPage.xaml.cs. Could you share the code for that?

Answer (score 1):

The `ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs` has an `ExceptionObject` property, this is the exception thrown. So query the content of the `e` argument.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.applicationunhandledexceptioneventargs.exceptionobject(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: can I also display the value of this property instead of comparing it to one that I might expect as in the page you mentioned

Comment: You can, it's a regular exception as you would normally get in a desktop app - you can show a message box with `e.ToString()` though this wouldn't be very usable.